# Youtube API v3 reading playlist

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube has close the api v2 so i have to rewrite some script to read youtube playlist.. i have managed to read the items in the playlist with ajax.

```
for (var i in data.items)
```

But i not seem to can read the title of the videos.
I have try :

```
data.items[i].title
```

but not seems to work.

here is a part of the data of youtube.

```
 "items": [
 {
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/nUoxGPc9-1QfJdGNICJpggBOQiw\"",
  "id": "PL00i2_BlzsBvKHcdXdtJhomEFSeHrz4oI",
  "snippet": {
   "publishedAt": "2015-05-15T06:06:55.000Z",
   "channelId": "UCKBfi2UItrlUlri-31wZTGA",
   "title": "Patrick Rosa - Angels in the sky (Teaser)",
```

What i do wrong, i m a bit lost.

Comment: Have you tried `data.items[i].snippet.title`?

Comment: Yes i did and i got it working :-) thanks.
i was a bit to fast with my question, i was not paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you all the titles in a specific playlist in JavaScript:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey('{YOUR-API-KEY}');
gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {

    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        playlistId: '{YOUR PLAYLIST ID}'
    });

    request.execute(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
            console.log(response.items[i].snippet.title);
        }
    });
});
```